# How to prove $\,\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}<\frac{3}{4}\,?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to prove $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}<\frac{3}{4}\;?$

To solve this problem, I found two series that converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ as follows, but I'm not sure what to do after this.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+n},\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1}$$
Is there only one way that compare it one by one by putting in the value directly?

Comment: For the upper bound, your argument could be that $n^2\ln n > n^2 > n^2-1$ so $\frac{1}{n^2\ln n} < \frac{1}{n^2-1}$  at least when $n \gt e$.  Because that is not the case for $n=2$, you would also need to check something like $\sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}} < \sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \frac{1}{n^2-1}$

Comment: I wonder if using integral $\int$ bounds/estimates is an easier approach.

Comment: so you say that put an value like 4, 5 in n to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2\ln n}>\sum\limits_{n=2}^4\dfrac1{n^2\ln n}>\dfrac12\,.$

Moreover,

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2\ln n}&<\dfrac1{4\ln2}+\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2\ln3}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac1{4\ln2}+\dfrac1{\ln3}\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}6-\dfrac54\right)<\dfrac34\,.\end{align}$

Comment: Aha, it's some correct to put the values one by one and compare them. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: So simple .... after reading the solution ! (+1) for sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

A similar start to Angelo's for the lower bound, but using one of your ideas for the upper bound:

- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^4\dfrac1{n^2\ln n} \approx 0.507$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^4\dfrac1{n^2-1} = \frac{21}{40}=0.525$
- $\dfrac1{n^2\ln n} >  \dfrac1{n^2} > \dfrac1{n^2-1}$ for $n\ge 3 > e$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2-1} = \frac34$

so

- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2\ln n} > \sum\limits_{n=2}^4\dfrac1{n^2\ln n}> \frac12$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2\ln n} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \dfrac1{n^2\ln n}+\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2\ln n} < \sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \dfrac1{n^2-1}+\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2-1} = \frac34 $

The actual sum is about $0.60552$.

Comment: There is a typo in your answer:$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2\ln n} = \sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \dfrac1{n^2\ln n}+\sum\limits_{n=\color{red}{\mathbf5}}^{\color{red}{\mathbf{\infty}}}\dfrac1{n^2\ln n} < \sum\limits_{n=2}^4 \dfrac1{n^2-1}+\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty \dfrac1{n^2-1} = \frac34 $$

Comment: @Angelo - yes - thank you - edited

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}<\frac{3}{4}$

The upper bound $\dfrac34$ is not the best; in fact

When $n\ge3$ we have  $\dfrac{1}{n^2\ln n}\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and because $\displaystyle\int_3^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=\dfrac13$ one has $\displaystyle\sum_3^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2\ln n}\lt\dfrac13$

It follows
$$\frac{1}{4\ln 2}+\sum_3^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2\ln n}\lt0.360673+\frac13=0.694007\lt0.75=\frac34$$
Respect to the lower bound it is given by the three first added
$\dfrac{1}{4\ln 2}+\dfrac{1}{9\ln 3}+\dfrac{1}{16\ln 4}\approx0.506895$